# What does add key value means in web.config file

Tags: web-services, iis-7.5

HI all i am trying to figure out the values and their meanings in web.config files, there are two lines which are not making sense to me if you can elaborate on this please.

```
<add key="Imp.Import.shops.FileLocation" value="C:\_imp\" />
<add key="Imp.Import.shops.ArchiveLocation" value="C:\_imp\_archive\" />
```

Comment: I mean what does the first line do and what does the second line would do.

Answer (score 1):

It just allows for many entries for a section, the `key` must be unique.  It's typically used when there is code written to look for that exact entry, for example the `appSettings` section of the web/app .config files are for general use.  For those values to be loaded and used you must add code to look for a specific key so there is an implied contract between adding an item in the appSettings and adding code to actually use it.

To read the setting value:

- Add a reference to System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

Code:

```
var archiveLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Imp.Import.shops.ArchiveLocation"];
```

If you didn't write the system then you can safely assume there is code written that needs to read these settings, the `key` identifies the setting by name.